# Copying a large directory tree locally? cp or rsync?

Tags: linux, unix, rsync, file-transfer, files

I have to copy a large directory tree, about 1.8 TB. It's all local. Out of habit I'd use `rsync`, however I wonder if there's much point, and if I should rather use `cp`.

I'm worried about permissions and uid/gid, since they have to be preserved in the copy (I know rsync does this). As well as things like symlinks.

The destination is empty, so I don't have to worry about conditionally updating some files. It's all local disk, so I don't have to worry about ssh or network.

The reason I'd be tempted away from rsync, is because rsync might do more than I need. rsync checksums files. I don't need that, and am concerned that it might take longer than cp.

So what do you reckon, `rsync` or `cp`?

Comment: If rsync does exactly what you want it to do, if you are quite familiar with its usage for this particular application already, and if it functions quickly enough to suit your taste, then why on earth would you want to switch?

Comment: Because I'm concerned that rsync will take longer than cp, since rsync does lots of checksumming that cp won't do

Comment: The cpu overhead of the checksum is small compared to the disk/network i/o.
Unless the disk are on the same system and the OS can do some clever drive-drive copy in the bus controller.

Comment: My understanding is that rsync only performs a checksum if you specify the -c flag. Otherwise, it compares file size and modification date.

Comment: Checksumming is done on files that differ at the size and timestamp check. If you're paranoid (like after a power outage during copy) you can force checksumming on all files, but on a local transfer, that's usually slower than starting from scratch.

Comment: Maybe he's curious about improving his workflow, and doesn't bury his head in the sand thinking he knows everything. This comment really annoys me.

Comment: `rsync` writes twice to the disk. It is approx double the time needed for `cp`. Only use `rsync` if you need to _sync_ files, e.g. copy only the updated files, incremental backups, etc, which is where `rsync` can effectively save the disk io. Otherwise, `cp` must be a double faster for a blank copy. [Not exactly the thing, but you can get an idea of "`rsync` writes twice" from here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291189/150246)

Answer (score 267, accepted):

I would use rsync as it means that if it is interrupted for any reason, then you can restart it easily with very little cost. And being rsync, it can even restart part way through a large file. As others mention, it can exclude files easily. The simplest way to preserve most things is to use the `-a` flag – ‘archive.’ So:

```
rsync -a source dest
```

Although UID/GID and symlinks are preserved by `-a` (see `-lpgo`), your question implies you might want a *full* copy of the filesystem information; and `-a` doesn't include hard-links, extended attributes, or ACLs (on Linux) or the above *nor* resource forks (on OS X.) Thus, for a robust copy of a filesystem, you'll need to include those flags:

```
rsync -aHAX source dest # Linux
rsync -aHE source dest  # OS X
```

The default cp will start again, though the `-u` flag will *"copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing"*. And the `-a` (archive) flag will be recursive, not recopy files if you have to restart and preserve permissions. So:

```
cp -au source dest
```

Comment: The -u flag of cp probably isn't the best solution, as it would not detect a partially copied/corrupted file.  The nice thing about rsync is that you can have it md5 sum the files to detect differences.

Comment: Adding -w (--whole-file) option would speed up an interrupted rsync, as it will just copy the file over instead of checksumming.

Comment: actually, rsync detects local transfers and enables whole-file copy without checksumming automagically.

Comment: and --progress which is really handy!

Comment: -P or --progress shows progress for each file individually. It's useful for copying large files, not for many (thousands) small files as it means lots more output which you can't read. It doesn't show the overal progress of all files combined.

Comment: I think you want `rsync -aHAX -vx src dst`. `H` preserves hard-links, `A` copies ACLs,  and `X` copies extended attributes. The `-vx` is optional, but it will print what it is doing (`v`) and restrict to one file system (`x`).

Comment: I'd second [Mark Grimes](http://serverfault.com/users/88224/mark-grimes)' comment, and add that on OS X you want `-E` instead of `-AX`. (Sadly, because `-aHAX` is hella easy to remember.)=

Comment: @SPRBRN -P implies --progress, but it also implies --partial, so -P and --partial are not the same.

Comment: I created myself a small reminder on what [options were best for backing up large directories](https://yalneb.blogspot.com.es/2017/05/rsync.html). Reading the other comments, I find it is basically a big agglomerate of those same options along a brief description (which can also be found on the man pages) of their effect on the copy-process. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: @SPRBRN Since rsync version 3.1.0 it supports `rsync --info=progress2` which does show the overall progress of the transfer (as best it can). Useful to give an approximation during large transfers.

Comment: @rlf Thanks a lot. That is epic. There are so many options for `--info`! I like `--info=name1`.

Comment: Actually, I discovered that rsync is much slower on my system than just copying with cp. This is why I always do the first, complete backup with `cp -avn`, then use rsync for any differential backups.

Comment: I've found it is faster to read the already copied data than to write it again. So use `--partial` (keep partial data for resume), `--no-whole-file` (re-read rather than re-write), and `--inplace` (avoid copy then replace). Avoid `--append-verify` due to a dangerous failure case. More details [here](https://serverfault.com/a/984080/322507).

Comment: Note that Mac's come with rsync v2 as default, so you need to upgrade to get `--info progress2` flag!

Answer (score 190):

When copying to the local file system I tend to use rsync with the following options:

```
# rsync -avhW --no-compress --progress /src/ /dst/
```

Here's my reasoning:

```
-a is for archive, which preserves ownership, permissions etc.
-v is for verbose, so I can see what's happening (optional)
-h is for human-readable, so the transfer rate and file sizes are easier to read (optional)
-W is for copying whole files only, without delta-xfer algorithm which should reduce CPU load
--no-compress as there's no lack of bandwidth between local devices
--progress so I can see the progress of large files (optional)
```

I've seen 17% faster transfers using the above rsync settings over the following tar command as suggested by another answer:

```
# (cd /src; tar cf - .) | (cd /dst; tar xpf -)
```

Comment: I am having following error: `rsync: --no-compress: unknown option` @Ellis Percival.

Comment: Like @alper, --no-compress wasn't an option for my version of rsync (in CentOS 7); I used --compress-level=0 instead.

Comment: above solution `--compress-level=0` on mac

Comment: I like this option, but progress can be unreadable if running through a large directory tree. Using `--info=progress2`  instead of `--progress` kept the progress info as a single updating line.

Answer (score 87):

When I have to copy a large amount of data, I usually use a combination of tar and rsync.  The first pass is to tar it, something like this:

```
# (cd /src; tar cf - .) | (cd /dst; tar xpf -)
```

Usually with a large amount of files, there will be some that tar can't handle for whatever reason.  Or maybe the process will get interrupted, or if it is a filesystem migration, the you might want to do the initial copy before the actual migration step.  At any rate, after the initial copy, I do an rsync step to sync it all up:

```
# cd /dst; rsync -avPHSx --delete /src/ .
```

Note that the trailing slash on `/src/` is important.

Comment: +1  I've found tar to generally be faster for large copies than rsync.  I like the idea of finishing off with a final rsync, too.

Comment: tar is a good choice if the dest dir is empty. Although my way would be: cd $DSTDIR; tar c -C $SRCDIR . | tar

Comment: Doesn't `tar`ing the file take up double the space? So if you're transferring `10 GB`, you'll need to reserve `20 GB` at the destination site? Just checking on this.

Comment: That's the beauty of this method.  You do not need double the space because you never actually create an intermediate tar file.  The tar before the pipe packs the data and streams it to stdout, and the tar after the pipe grabs it from stdin and unpacks it.

Comment: I did a cp -a for a 12gb transfer, and this method for a 42gb transfer. The tar method took about 1/4 the time.

Comment: I thinkt you should allways add -S to both tar and rsync so that sparse files won't grow on the destination.

Comment: Just tried it. The tar solution is definitely the fastest on large amounts of little files.

Comment: furthermore, `mbuffer` could by used to reduce some random read/write lag effects

Comment: No need for subshells: `tar -C /src -c . | tar -C /dst -xp`

Comment: I also put `pv` in the middle to be able to watch the progress, estimating the size of all the data using `df`. I also used `--numeric-owner`, as the source disk was from another system and I didn't want `tar` to mess the owners: `tar -C /old-path --numeric-owner -S -c . | pv -tpeba -s 100G | tar -C /new-path --numeric-owner -S -xp`

Comment: This only makes sense when copying from one block device to another, right? I can't see a reason to do this on the same disk.

Comment: I wonder why `tar` method is faster than `rsync` or `cp`

Answer (score 16):

### rsync

Here is the rsync I use, I prefer cp for simple commands, not this.

```
$ rsync -ahSD --ignore-errors --force --delete --stats $SRC/ $DIR/
```

### cpio

Here is a way that is even safer, cpio.  It's about as fast as tar, maybe a little quicker.

```
$ cd $SRC && find . -mount -depth -print0 2>/dev/null | cpio -0admp $DEST &>/dev/null
```

### tar

This is also good, and continues on read-failures.

```
$ tar --ignore-failed-read -C $SRC -cf - . | tar --ignore-failed-read -C $DEST -xf -
```

Note those are all just for local copies.

Comment: Why do you use the -S and -D flags for rsync?

Comment: `D` preserves Specials and System files, while `S` "handle sparse files efficiently" not sure why rsync wouldn't just do that by default.

Comment: In what way is cpio safer than rsync?

Comment: Why do you use --ignore-errors and --ignore-failed-read? Is it for safety?

Answer (score 16):

This thread was very useful and because there were so many options to achieve the result, I decided to benchmark few of them. I believe my results can be helpful to others have a sense of what worked faster.

To move **532Gb** of data distributed among **1,753,200 files** we had those times:

- `rsync` took 232 minutes
- `tar` took 206 minutes
- `cpio` took 225 minutes
- `rsync + parallel` took 209 minutes

On my case I preferred to use `rsync + parallel`. I hope this information helps more people to decide among these alternatives.

The complete benchmark are published [here](http://arjon.es/2017/05/11/which-is-the-best-tool-for-copying-a-large-directory-tree-locally/)

Comment: 404 page not found

Comment: Thanks @AmedeeVanGasse URL have been fixed a short after you reported :)

Comment: Why not benchmarking `cp`? This is the title of the question!

Comment: @calandoa I think `cp` is insecure, ie: when it breaks you have to start over, that's way I favor options that can resume, ergo `rsync` is my favorite :)

Comment: On a 70GB file system, with 48GB data - block size 1024 - with 385000 files and 427730 directories - `cp` was about 3 minutes faster than `rsync` and `find + cpio`. 18m30s to 22min.

Answer (score 8):

The `rsync` command always computes checksums on every byte it transfers.

The command line option `--checksum` only relates to whether checksums of files are used to determine which files to transfer or not, ie:

> `-c, --checksum`  skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size"

The manpage also says this:

> Note that rsync always verifies that each transferred file was correctly reconstructed on the receiving side by checking its whole-file checksum, but that automatic after-the-transfer verification has nothing to do with this option’s before-the-transfer "Does this file need to be updated?" check.

So `rsync` also, always, calculates a checksum of the whole file on the receiving side, even when `-c/ --checksum` option is "off".

Comment: While your post added some interesting information here, the rants, and insults decrease the value of your post.  This site is not a forum for un-constructive rants.  If you were able to modify the source, have you submitted your modifications as a patch?  Have you posted your version on github or something?  If you feel so strongly about this, it might be better if you tried to do something a bit more constructive instead of being needlessly insulting.

Comment: Yeah, the last paragraph wasn't really necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Whatever you prefer. Just don't forget the `-a` switch when you decide to use `cp`.

If you really need an answer: I'd use rsync because it's much more flexible. Need to shutdown before copying is complete? Just ctrl-c and resume as soon as your back. Need to exclude some files? Just use `--exclude-from`. Need to change ownership or permissions? rsync will do that for you.

Comment: What does the -p flag do again?

Comment: It will Preserver ownership, timestamps and permissions.

Comment: cp -a would be better.

Comment: Indeed. Answer changed accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

`rsync -aPhW --protocol=28` helps speed up those large copies with RSYNC. I always go rsync because the thought of being midway through 90GiB and it breaking scares me away from CP

Comment: What is the value of using the older protocol in that command string?

Comment: On a mac machine the older version of Rsync shipped hangs on some newer rsync protocol revs such as 29. Telling it to move to the older protocol makes it NOT check over and over again.

Comment: I guess that number 28 is not valid anymore?

Answer (score 5):

rsync is great, but has issues with really large directory trees because it stores the trees in memory.  I was just looking to see if they'd fix this problem when I found this thread.

I also found:

http://matthew.mceachen.us/geek/gigasync/

You could also manually break up the tree and run multiple rsyncs.

Comment: If you use version 3 it doesn't keep the whole tree in memory if it is big, it uses a incremental-recursion algorithm: http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-3.0.0-NEWS

Answer (score 4):

You definitely want to give [rclone](https://rclone.org/) a try. This thing is crazy fast :

```
sudo rclone sync /usr /home/fred/temp -P -L --transfers 64

Transferred:       17.929G / 17.929 GBytes, 100%, 165.692 MBytes/s, ETA 0s
Errors:                75 (retrying may help)
Checks:            691078 / 691078, 100%
Transferred:       345539 / 345539, 100%
Elapsed time:     1m50.8s
```

This is a local copy from and to a LITEONIT LCS-256 (256GB) SSD.

You can add `--ignore-checksum` on the first run to make it even faster.

Comment: There are some limitations to rclone, but it does seem to be a relatively easy way to take full advantage of your CPU and I/O resources. I haven't figured out if there's an easy way to tell it to copy multiple directories from one directory to another, but I can always script that if need be.

Comment: `rclone` cannot make an identical copy of a Linux/Unix file system.  It cannot preserve hard links, and the `-L` option you give above makes it follow symbolic links instead of ignoring them, which will send it into an infinite loop if you have a symlink such as `/usr/local -> .`  Do not use this to make a local copy of a directory tree.

Comment: @IanD.Allen It depends on what you want. If you want to copy symlinks as symlinks you can use `--links, -l`. For example use `rclone sync -P -l --create-empty-src-dirs --no-update-modtime --transfers 256 --checkers 256 --fast-list /source /destination` You're right about hard links though. Documentation: https://rclone.org/local/

Comment: rclone does not preserve the permissions and ownership.

Answer (score 4):

There are some speed-ups which can be applied to `rsync`:

#### Avoid

- `-z`/`--compress`: compression will only load up the CPU as the transfer isn't over a network but over RAM.
- `--append-verify`: resume an interrupted transfer. This sounds like a good idea, but it has the dangerous failure case: any destination file the same size (or greater) than the source will be IGNORED. Also, it checksums the whole file at the end, meaning no significant speed up over `--no-whole-file` while adding a dangerous failure case.

#### Use

- `-S`/`--sparse`: turn sequences of nulls into sparse blocks
- `--partial` or `-P` which is `--partial --progress`: save any partially transferred files for future resuming. Note: files won't have a temporary name, so ensure that nothing else is expecting to use the destination until the whole copy has completed.
- `--no-whole-file` so that anything that needs to be resent uses delta transfer. Reading half of a partially transferred file is often much quicker than writing it again.
- `--inplace` to avoid file copy (but only if nothing is reading the destination until the whole transfer completes)

Answer (score 3):

When doing local a local directory copy, my experience is that "cp -van src dest" is 20% faster than rsync.  As far as restartability, that's what "-n" does.  You just need to rm the partially copied file.  Not painful unless it's an ISO or some such.

Answer (score 2):

`tar` would also do the job, but won't resume from being interrupted like rsync will.

Comment: An old answer, but isn't TAR for creating compressed archives of files? How could it be used to transfer files like rsync or cp?

Comment: @SherwinFlight cd source ; tar cf - . | ( cd dest ; tar xf - )

Answer (score 2):

ARJ IS SO OLD SCHOOL!! I really doubt that ARJ and/or rsync will give performance.

Definitely what I always do is use cpio:

```
find . -print | cpio -pdm /target/folder
```

This is almost fast than CP, definitely faster than tar and without pipeing anything.

Comment: "The original cpio and find utilities were written by Dick Haight while working in AT&T's Unix Support Group.  They first appeared in 1977 in PWB/UNIX 1.0" - FreeBSD's `cpio` man page.

Comment: `cpio` unfortunately has an 8GB upper limit for files.

Comment: "*without pipeing anything*" [sic]. Except the `find` command, as you listed it, has a pipe in it: `find . -print | cpio -pdm /target/folder`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in need to copy large amount of small files between two local mounts (in my case it was two NFS mounts of a NAS service from a cloud provider):

`cp` was painfully slow. When watching network throughput, I saw it could only saturate about 1 mbps of bandwidth. Then I tried with tar:

`tar -pc /mnt/old-nas | tar -xpf - -C /mnt/new-nas`

which could saturate the line fully, between 250-300 mbps.

Tar seems to perform much better when copying between two mountpoints with high latency.

Answer (score 1):

If both storages are local, **cp** should transfer data near maximum possible speed. It is not necessary to use a synchronizer if the target directory is empty, but it brings benefits like restartability, possibility to exclude certain files etc.

**rsync** is strong in copying over network (delta transfer of big files). But **rsync** keeps its internal data in memory, which may cause problems with huge directory trees.

If you are interested in another synchronizer, you might have a look at [Fitus/Zaloha.sh](https://github.com/Fitus/Zaloha.sh). It runs **find** on both directories and prepares scripts with **cp** commands. It keeps its internal data in files, not in memory. It is used as follows:

```
$ Zaloha.sh --sourceDir="test_source" --backupDir="test_backup"
```

If you want it to just generate the **cp** script (but not execute it, which would require extensive display and interaction), use the --noExec option.

Your use case presumably does not require generation of restore scripts: use the --noRestore option. Last, if you have the fast **mawk** installed, make use of it via the --mawk option.

Answer (score 0):

Both will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use ARJ?

```
arj a -jm -m1 -r -je filepack /source
```

where `-jm -m1` are compression levels and `-je` makes it an executable. Now you have a encapsulated bash of files.

Then for extraction to the target map

```
filepack -y
```

where the source map will be made (where `-y` is always accept, overwrite, skip etc)

One can then scp ftp the filepack to the target area and execute it, if that is possible.

Comment: Arj? Didn't that die out in the 80's?

Comment: maybe the early 90's if you believe wikipedia

Comment: It assumes you have the 50% free disk space for the resulting file which is not true when I try to transfer my nas, and second why would I not just do a tar file?